# biblatex-dw bibliography formatting @incollection volume number after series name

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-dw

In order to meet the publication criteria for a book, I need some custom formatting for the bibliography, especially `@incollection` items:

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{page}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    and={/},
    page={},
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
    editor = {{ Hg\adddot }} ,
    editors = {{ Hg\adddot }}
}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}

    @book{b2,
        year = {2014},
        title = {Redefreiheit: Öffentliche Debatten der Bevölkerung im Herbst 1989},
        address = {Leipzig},
        edition = {1. Aufl.},
        publisher = {Leipziger Uni-Vlg},
        isbn = {386583888X},
        editor = {Ahbe, Thomas and Stiehler, Volker and Hofmann, Michael},
        shorttitle = {Redefreiheit}
    }

    @incollection{bauer,
        xref = {schwobel},
        author = {Bauer, Gisa},
        title = {Transformationen des Religiösen: Die historisch-materialistische Geschichtsschreibung in der DDR als Heilsgeschichte},
        volume = {39},
        series = {VWGTh},
        editor = {Schwöbel, Christoph},
        booktitle = {Geschichte und Gott},
        address = {Leipzig},
        shorttitle = {Transformationen}
    }

    @book{schwobel,
        title = {Geschichte und Gott: XV. Europäischer Kongress für Theologie},
        address = {Leipzig},
        volume = {39},
        series = {VWGTh},
        editor = {Schwöbel, Christoph},
        shorttitle = {Geschichte}
    }
    @book{bulischop.2006,
        author = {Bulisch, Jens},
        year = {2006},
        title = {Evangelische Presse in der DDR},
        address = {Göttingen},
        volume = {43},
        publisher = {Vandenhoeck und Ruprecht},
        isbn = {3525557442},
        series = {AKZG},
        shorttitle = {Presse}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{file.bib}
\begin{document}
    text \footcite{bulischop.2006} text.
    text \footcite{bauer} haha. 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I would need the following change to bibliography formatting see picture:

[image: descriptive image]

1. For books with a series: the volume number should be placed after the series name, but inside the round brackets (i.e. (AKZG 43)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the number in a `series` use the `number` field (and *not* the `volume` field).

```
@collection{schwobel,
  title      = {Geschichte und Gott: XV. Europäischer Kongress für Theologie},
  address    = {Leipzig},
  number     = {39},
  series     = {VWGTh},
  editor     = {Schwöbel, Christoph},
  shorttitle = {Geschichte},
}
@book{bulischop.2006,
  author     = {Bulisch, Jens},
  year       = {2006},
  title      = {Evangelische Presse in der DDR},
  address    = {Göttingen},
  number     = {43},
  publisher  = {Vandenhoeck und Ruprecht},
  isbn       = {3525557442},
  series     = {AKZG},
  shorttitle = {Presse},
}
```

BTW: `bauer` can be made shorter with `crossref` instead of `xref`

```
@incollection{bauer,
  crossref   = {schwobel},
  author     = {Bauer, Gisa},
  title      = {Transformationen des Religiösen},
  subtitle   = {Die historisch-materialistische Geschichtsschreibung in der DDR als Heilsgeschichte},
  shorttitle = {Transformationen}
}
```

You will also want to use

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    andothers = {et\,al\adddot},
    editor    = {Hg\adddot} ,
    editors   = {Hg\adddot}
}
```

---

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{page}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    andothers = {et\,al\adddot},
    editor    = {Hg\adddot} ,
    editors   = {Hg\adddot}
}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

    @book{b2,
        year = {2014},
        title = {Redefreiheit: Öffentliche Debatten der Bevölkerung im Herbst 1989},
        address = {Leipzig},
        edition = {1. Aufl.},
        publisher = {Leipziger Uni-Vlg},
        isbn = {386583888X},
        editor = {Ahbe, Thomas and Stiehler, Volker and Hofmann, Michael},
        shorttitle = {Redefreiheit}
    }

@incollection{bauer,
  crossref   = {schwobel},
  author     = {Bauer, Gisa},
  title      = {Transformationen des Religiösen},
  subtitle   = {Die historisch-materialistische Geschichtsschreibung in der DDR als Heilsgeschichte},
  shorttitle = {Transformationen}
}

@collection{schwobel,
  title      = {Geschichte und Gott: XV. Europäischer Kongress für Theologie},
  address    = {Leipzig},
  number     = {39},
  series     = {VWGTh},
  editor     = {Schwöbel, Christoph},
  shorttitle = {Geschichte},
}
@book{bulischop.2006,
  author     = {Bulisch, Jens},
  year       = {2006},
  title      = {Evangelische Presse in der DDR},
  address    = {Göttingen},
  number     = {43},
  publisher  = {Vandenhoeck und Ruprecht},
  isbn       = {3525557442},
  series     = {AKZG},
  shorttitle = {Presse},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
    text \footcite{bulischop.2006} text.
    text \footcite{bauer} haha. 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: bibliography (page 3) of MWE]

Comment: Using number does not change the display. It still shows as Bd. 43 (AKZG) not as (AKZG 43).

Comment: I know about xref, but the bibliogrpahy is huge and I dont want to spend the time editing everything.

Comment: @Philipp I can hardly believe that. Please show an MWE of how `number` does not work for you.

Comment: This is very weird. It must be because of my setup. XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/Debian), biber version: 2.4. I have no clue. Do you have an idea? I am using the MWE as you provide it and get the same result as in my question.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, sorry. Problem solved! Didn't run biber to update. Stupid mistakes...

Comment: Do you have an idea regarding my other question - last name first name sorting for the editor? i.e. SCHWOEBEL Christoph instead Christoph SCHWOEBEL