# biblatex: do not display editor first name

Tags: biblatex

I want to remove the display of the first name of the editor in the bibliography.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{page}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{last-first}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    and={/},
    page={},
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
    editor = {{ Hg\adddot }} ,
    editors = {{ Hg\adddot }}
}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}

    @book{b2,
        year = {2014},
        title = {Redefreiheit: Öffentliche Debatten der Bevölkerung im Herbst 1989},
        address = {Leipzig},
        edition = {1. Aufl.},
        publisher = {Leipziger Uni-Vlg},
        isbn = {386583888X},
        editor = {Ahbe, Thomas and Stiehler, Volker and Hofmann, Michael},
        shorttitle = {Redefreiheit}
    }

    @incollection{bauer,
        xref = {schwobel},
        author = {Bauer, Gisa},
        title = {Transformationen des Religiösen: Die historisch-materialistische Geschichtsschreibung in der DDR als Heilsgeschichte},
        volume = {39},
        series = {VWGTh},
        editor = {Schwöbel, Christoph},
        booktitle = {Geschichte und Gott},
        address = {Leipzig},
        shorttitle = {Transformationen}
    }

    @book{schwobel,
        title = {Geschichte und Gott: XV. Europäischer Kongress für Theologie},
        address = {Leipzig},
        volume = {39},
        series = {VWGTh},
        editor = {Schwöbel, Christoph},
        shorttitle = {Geschichte}
    }
    @book{bulischop.2006,
        author = {Bulisch, Jens},
        year = {2006},
        title = {Evangelische Presse in der DDR},
        address = {Göttingen},
        volume = {43},
        publisher = {Vandenhoeck und Ruprecht},
        isbn = {3525557442},
        series = {AKZG},
        shorttitle = {Presse}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{file.bib}
\begin{document}
    text \footcite{bulischop.2006} text.
    text \footcite{bauer} haha. 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code still contains some problems that I have probably already noted in other questions of yours. In my answers to your questions I have changed your `\DefineBibliographyStrings` to something more sensible with the same output, if it was in my code (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369368/). In particular you should not have the spaces in `editor = {{ Hg\adddot }} ,` they result in terrible spaces after the opening bracket in '( Hg.)', with the more sensible `editor = {Hg\adddot},` (no spaces, no need for double braces either) you get the much more aesthetically pleasing '(Hg.)'.

Comment: @moewe, I know and have fixed this in the actual current version. I am just copying old examples to quickly show what I need to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using moewe's answer to [Enable “firstinits” in biblatex only for editors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173782/105447) and adjusting it to current `biblatex` name formatting terminology (as in Ulrike Fisher's answer to [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299084/105447)), you could use:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{only-family}

\DeclareNameFormat{only-family}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

The result is:

[image]

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{page}{#1}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{last-first}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    and={/},
    page={},
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
    editor = {{ Hg\adddot }} ,
    editors = {{ Hg\adddot }}
}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}

    @book{b2,
        year = {2014},
        title = {Redefreiheit: Öffentliche Debatten der Bevölkerung im Herbst 1989},
        address = {Leipzig},
        edition = {1. Aufl.},
        publisher = {Leipziger Uni-Vlg},
        isbn = {386583888X},
        editor = {Ahbe, Thomas and Stiehler, Volker and Hofmann, Michael},
        shorttitle = {Redefreiheit}
    }

    @incollection{bauer,
        xref = {schwobel},
        author = {Bauer, Gisa},
        title = {Transformationen des Religiösen: Die historisch-materialistische Geschichtsschreibung in der DDR als Heilsgeschichte},
        volume = {39},
        series = {VWGTh},
        editor = {Schwöbel, Christoph},
        booktitle = {Geschichte und Gott},
        address = {Leipzig},
        shorttitle = {Transformationen}
    }

    @book{schwobel,
        title = {Geschichte und Gott: XV. Europäischer Kongress für Theologie},
        address = {Leipzig},
        volume = {39},
        series = {VWGTh},
        editor = {Schwöbel, Christoph},
        shorttitle = {Geschichte}
    }
    @book{bulischop.2006,
        author = {Bulisch, Jens},
        year = {2006},
        title = {Evangelische Presse in der DDR},
        address = {Göttingen},
        volume = {43},
        publisher = {Vandenhoeck und Ruprecht},
        isbn = {3525557442},
        series = {AKZG},
        shorttitle = {Presse}
    }
\end{filecontents}


\addbibresource{file.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{only-family}

\DeclareNameFormat{only-family}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\begin{document}
    text \footcite{bulischop.2006} text.
    text \footcite{bauer} haha. 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Update**: Depending on your exact requirements (e.g., if you want disambiguation checks to be made on the editor's name), you might also simply go with:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{labelname}
```

Comment: Off-topic. I'm not sure you want that space between "(" and "Hg." as rendered by your redefined bibliography strings.

Comment: I need to completely remove the first name - not even ", C." has to appear.

Comment: Oh, I see, I had misunderstood that. I'll update the answer accordingly.